# C++ - how to check if char* points to something valid?

Tags: c++, char

I want to check if a char* points to a valid string...Can I check this variable...

```
char* c;
```

What I tried:

```
if(c == NULL)  //c is not null
if(*c == '\0') //false
if(strlen(c) == 0)  //exception
```

I think it is not possible to check a char* when it was not allocated and dont point to a valid string...

Comment: And why would you want to check an uninitialized pointer's value?

Comment: I solved my Problem with this way:

the char* is a member variable...So I specified at the constructor:

    Session::Session()
        :c(0) {}

and now if the char* is not allocated I can check it with

    if(0 != c) { /*is allocated*/ }

Answer (score 5):

Truth is, you can't ever be sure a pointer is valid. Testing for NULL may give you certainty that it is invalid, but it doesn't guarantee any validity. That's one reason not to use this kind of thing in C++. A `std::string` is *always* in a valid state.

Answer (score 4):

If the pointer is not `NULL`, there is no way of saying if the value of the pointer is valid or not.

Comment: Isn't it fair to say that `char`, unless initialized or assigned to, is *always* invalid?

Comment: @jrok: That would depend on the storage class of the char, for ex: globals and static will be initialized even if not explictly.

Answer (score 2):

c can point anywhere. This might be a null terminated string, a string without terminating null byte, any accessible binary data or any address that is not accessible. What exactly do you want to check for and why? If you want to differentiate between a valid string and a not-initialized, you would normally use NULL for the uninitialized case and check c==NULL. Accessing *c (strlen does this, too) is not OK if c is not a valid pointer. So a typical usecase would be like this:

```
// initializing to NULL
char *c = NULL;
// maybe setting value
if(condition)
  c = strdup("mein string");
// cleanup
if(c != NULL) {
  free(c);
  c = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an upper bound on the size of the string you expect:

```
char * c = new char[size];
```

then perhaps you can check if it terminates within the bound:

```
bool is_valid(char *c, size_t size) { 
     while (size--) if (*c) return true;
     return false;
   }
```

another way is encapsulating the char * within a class in the constructor, or to have a valid flag in such a class.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the O/S.  Under Windows you have the `IsBadXxxPtr()` family of functions which will test for a pointer to valid memory, although they won't test if the pointer is to a valid instance of a particular type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366713(v=vs.85).aspx
etc.

Comment: Please don't recommend the `CrashProgramRandomly` family of functions. https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=oldnewthing&y=2006&m=09&d=27&WeblogPostID=773741&GroupKeys=

Comment: These functions are k.own to be dangerous. Do not use them under any circumstances.